# Webpack 2 beta + history API fallback not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Today, after removing my node_modules and reinstalling them using npm install, my project doesn't seem to work.

Here's my webpack config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const srcPath = path.join(__dirname, './client');
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isProd = nodeEnv === 'production';

module.exports = {
  devtool: isProd ? 'hidden-source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  context: path.join(__dirname, './client'),
  entry: {
    js: './index.js',
    vendor: ['react']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './static'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'file',
        query: {
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(txt|json)/,
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve('./client'),
      'node_modules'
    ],
    alias: {
      stores: `${srcPath}/stores/`,
      components: `${srcPath}/components/`,
      services: `${srcPath}/services`,
      models: `${srcPath}/models`,
      constants: `${srcPath}/constants`,
      sources: `${srcPath}/sources`,
      images: `${srcPath}/assets/images`,
      appConstants: isProd ? `${srcPath}/constants/_prod` : `${srcPath}/constants/_dev`
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/regenerator|nodent|js\-beautify/, /ajv/),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: Infinity,
      filename: 'vendor.bundle.js'
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: isProd
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: !isProd
      },
      output: {
        comments: !isProd
      },
      sourceMap: !isProd
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv) }
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './client',
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

My "client" folder with index.html and the rest of my code are in the same folder as webpack config.

Webpack does succesfully build, but going to `localhost:3000`, I get error message: "Cannot GET /"

Going to `localhost:3000/client/index.html` does serve my index.html, but my built files inserted using

```
<script src="./vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./bundle.js"></script>
```

doesn't load (GET to "http://localhost:3000/client/bundle.js" results in 404)

Anyone knows what's going on? I can't fix this issue, and I think I've tried everything, from changing path, publicPath to changing contentBase and moving my static files to different folder.
It's very strange, since this issue appeared only after reinstalling my project dependencies.

Every bit of help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue in `webpack-dev-server@2.1.0-beta.3`, which caused the `contentBase` option to be ignored. Could you try upgrading to `2.1.0-beta.4`? It was just released.